# CMake Project for the STM32H757I-Eval Board

Tags: c++, cmake, embedded, stm32, stm32h7

I am trying Visual Studio's new feature of [importing an STM32CubeIDE Project](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/importing-st-projects-into-visual-studio/) (making it a CMake Project) and have a problem:
Visual Studio Import Feature only works with single-core boards, and unfortunately, I only have dual-core boards;
Anyways... it asks for the `.cproject` file, but we kinda have 2 of them - one for each core;

VS allows you to import only 1 `.cproject` at a time, which means you'd have to do the importing process 2x, but then VS thinks these are 2 separate projects and makes no linking, whatsoever.

In the CubeIDE we build the project and we also get to choose the debug configuration, thereby I choose, for example, another port for CM4-debugging, connect under reset, that I want CM7 to load the code for CM4, and so on.

We then get this `<project_name> Debug.launch` file inside each core folder.

I'd would like to replicate that (launching of one core using the other) using CMake.

Does anyone have an idea how I could accomplish that?

I am already working on the other configurations. For example, importing the 2 `.cprojects` separately, and once we get the `CMakeLists.txt` and the `/cmake`, I create a root `CMakeLists.txt` that only sets up the project(instead of already "adding an st-target" with the name of the project, as the generated ones do), then to go into the CM4 and CM7 folders and, by using the rest code of the generated `CMakeLists.txt` files, create the target, this time with 2 separate names reflecting the CM7 and CM4 cores.

I'll also modify the generated CMake modules (`gcc-arm-none-eabi.cmake` and `st-project.cmake`) to perform a check (if CM4 or CM7 is passed) and then modify the files/directory/names accordingly.

There should be something like creating the CM4_Target as a library, and the CM7 one as an executable; then, statically link the CM4_Target (lib) to the CM7_Target (exe) and then run/execute it.

See the picture below to have an idea of what I am trying to accomplish ahah.
Also note that those .c files will most probably be .cpp files (I intend to develop in C++).

[image: project_tree]

I also asked the ST Community and also commented on Microsoft's Post(more than a week ago, actually), but still waiting for a response :/

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would say: forget about VS is you work with embedded targets. It only works on simple led-flash apps but not when you try to do something more sophisticated. Stick to Eclipse-based IDEs as they work. If you use VS you will spend 90% of your time trying to work around its limitations, bugs and misconceptions.

Comment: Thank you for those heads-up. Yeah, that's what I noticed. They shouldn't even advertise that. I mean, the idea is nice - converting the Cube project into a CMake Project - but if that doesn't work, then why bother? 
Anyway... I just thought I could have everything in one place, etc. haha, but that ain't happening yet.

Comment: My boss likes VS but he uses it only for editing - but compiles and debugs using the proper embedded IDE. I do not bother - Eclipse editor is working the same fine as VS but I do not have to waste my time patching the build system. On top of that eclipse has plenty of handy Cortex-M and STM plugins saving you plenty time (for example hard fault resolver reading the registers and stack for you and displaying it in the convenient form - you can even jump to the code which is at the address shown by the registers.

Comment: I see! But I'm kinda sad; I wish I could do some Embedded stuff in a C+++CMake way, even if doing it from the CubeIDE (hence, taking advantage of Eclipse/STM stuff); but that's rubbish; CubeIDE doesn't even react when you choose C++ as the language upon project creation; I don't even understand why they offer that haha - they create the main's.c etc. the same way. Nothing changes.

Comment: Basically it cant change. What would you expect from the C++ project? HAL is written C style, CMSIS too. Only your code can be C++. So the process creation will be 100% the same unless HAL & CMSIS are object oriented

Comment: HUH, I see your point. Good point haha!

Well, then I guess I should just accept that programming STM32 MCUs is C and that's it haha - all the workarounds may not be worth it the time.

Comment: No - your code can be C++ or you will need to rewrite HAL library to be OO